# What will replace Tomboy in 12.04?

Tags: tomboy, 12.04

I heard that Tomboy is being removed in Ubuntu 12.04. I use it extensively and since it is connected to Ubuntu One I figured they will have a new way to sync notes. right? I'll be very very sad if I lose all my notes.

Comment: As far as I know you can import your Tomboy notes to Gnotes.

Comment: Being an "Ubuntu+1" question, this may be [too localized](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions).

Comment: try gnote. it imported all my tomboy notes automatically.

Answer (score 12):

I too am saddened by the loss of Tomboy from the **default** installation - but don't worry.

Our notes will remain intact - upgrading from 11.10 will still leave Tomboy installed.  For new installs, you can simply download tomboy from the Software Centre.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: I heard about them dropping couchdb and someone said that had to do with our notes, so doesn't that mean we will lose all our notes? I use them quite a bit and would like to continue to do so.

Comment: @MatthewLynnWallace: it would only be the syncing that they are changing. The notes are saved in ~/.local/share/tomboy

Comment: yes, but will i be able to sync notes still is the question. Because I use the notes sync for work.

Comment: @MatthewLynnWallace yes - they are working on a couch db replacement, and even if they don't, you can manually sync the folder.